# Ember.js and Isotope.js - Executing Javascript after all childviews became rendered

Tags: events, ember.js, view, rendering

I use Ember.js (1.0. RC) and would like to apply Isotope.js's functionality to some of my views located in a "container".

So my route basically loads the models containing the needed data from a server, sets up the controller's content and binds it to the model's data, which works fine.

Next I declared a template for my IndexRoute which iterates over all the loaded items like this:

```
{{each item in this itemViewClass="App.ItemView"}}
```

The items are the images that should be filtered with isotope.js. ItemView only refers to a simple template for the time being.

The execution chain is the following: Route -> Fetching model data -> Set up controllers -> Create IndexView -> Pile up all the ItemViews in a DIV-container.

Now I need to check whether all the ItemViews are loaded and the rendering is finally finished to apply isotope.js's filtering functionality but I can't figure out how to do that.

The `didInsertElement` of the IndexView event fires as soon as it's been rendered and before the ItemViews were added to the DOM.

I already tried to set up a `ContainerView` which would work in conjunction with `Ember.run.scheduleOnce("afterRender"...)` if I didn't fetch the data through the models but hardcoded it to the `content` variable.

The `CollectionView` also did me no favor with this exercise.

Any ideas how to solve that misery? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: A jsfiddle replicating your issue would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how exactly isotope.js works..considering its just a jquery plugin, you can call isotope like this even if it is a `ContainerView` or `CollectionView`.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
   Ember.run.next(this, function(){
     this.$().isotope({}) // or watever code u want to write
   });
}
```

This makes sure that the code inside ember.run runs once rendering is done completely..

Comment: looks like its just a work around..there is a talk to support `afterRender` by deprecating `run.next()`...but i hope they solve issues like this ContainerView rendering and all... https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2294

Comment: unfortunately `afterRender` did not achieve the same results as `run.next()` does. Not sure why.

Comment: yea i know that...even i have faced same issue...i think they know that and correct soon..